# Change a button background from code c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I try to change WP8 button background from code. I have the variable

```
private Color bColor = new Color() { R = 74, G = 10, B = 180 };
```

And I try to do

```
mButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(bColor);
```

But it's don't work. How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set Alpha:

```
 private Color bColor = new Color() { R = 74, G = 10, B = 180, A = 0xFF };
```

You would be better off using the construction methods, like `Color.FromArgb()`